# Mysql8 partition by month, partition pruning not working

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I have a large table that I have partitioned by month

```
CREATE TABLE `log` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `logdate` date NOT NULL,
 ...
,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`logdate`)
) PARTITION BY RANGE (month(`logdate`))
(PARTITION part0 VALUES LESS THAN (2),
 PARTITION part1 VALUES LESS THAN (3),
 PARTITION part2 VALUES LESS THAN (4),
 PARTITION part3 VALUES LESS THAN (5),
 PARTITION part4 VALUES LESS THAN (6),
 PARTITION part5 VALUES LESS THAN (7),
 PARTITION part6 VALUES LESS THAN (8),
 PARTITION part7 VALUES LESS THAN (9),
 PARTITION part8 VALUES LESS THAN (10),
 PARTITION part9 VALUES LESS THAN (11),
 PARTITION part10 VALUES LESS THAN (12),
 PARTITION part11 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE);
```

I have inserted 3 months of data and can see that the rows have been put into their respective partitions.

When I query specifying the partition, the correct data is returned and the `explain` shows that it is selecting from the correct partition

```
select logdate, sum(total) from log partition(part10) 
                where logdate between '2020-11-01' and '2020-11-30' group by 1 order by 1 desc;
```

However when not specifying the partition no partition pruning is occurring for the below.

```
select logdate, sum(total) from log 
                where logdate between '2020-11-01' and '2020-11-30' group by 1 order by 1 desc;


select logdate, sum(total) from log 
                where month(logdate) = 11 group by 1 order by 1 desc;
```

According to mysql-8 documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-range.html

> Partitioning schemes based on time intervals.  If you wish to implement a partitioning scheme based on ranges or intervals of time in MySQL 8.0, you have two options:

> 1. Partition the table by RANGE, and for the partitioning expression, employ a function operating on a DATE, TIME, or DATETIME column and returning an integer value  **- as shown here in my code**

> 2. Partition the table by RANGE COLUMNS, using a DATE or DATETIME column as the partitioning column.

What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps a little dated, and still a hideous read, but nevertheless essentially reading for anyone thinking about using partitions: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for the read.  Only possibility I could see is to drop and recreate indexes, putting the `partition field` at the end.

Comment: Well, you could simply not have any partitions

Comment: @Strawberry Not quite sure what you are suggesting here.

Comment: What benefit do you think the partitions provide?

Comment: @Strawberry My customer is inserting 9 millions rows per day, but is only reporting on the last three months, but wants to hold 12 months of data.  I have created some summary tables, but that solution is only taking me so far.

Comment: I don't really understand, but OK, and how does partitioning help with that ( other than by allowing  the deletion of the oldest month on a monthly rolling basis)

Comment: @Strawberry reading from just one partition (as a lot of the sql does) will be a lot quicker than reading the entire data.  Indexes will not fit in memory.

Comment: But it's *not* reading from one partition, is it? Besides, I'm very sceptical of these sorts of blanket assertions without testing to prove their veracity. I'm not saying it's not true, but if it was me, I'd like to know for sure.

Comment: If the data is partitioned by month, then why does `select logdate, sum(total) from log 
                where month(logdate) = 11 group by 1 order by 1 desc;` not just read one partition?  Whether or not I specify the `partition` keyword, the data returned in the same.

Comment: I can't comment on that. However, in general, if you want to select data from a given month (after all, you're only storing 12 months of data) then the normal approach is with a range query (`logdate >= '2020-11-01 AND logdate < '2020-12-01'`)

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, I understand that.  As I wrote in my question `select logdate, sum(total) from log 
                where logdate between '2020-11-01' and '2020-11-30' group by 1 order by 1 desc;` is also not working (`explain` shows what partitions are being queried).  I guess that you can not help.

Comment: I'm only speculating, but it seems to me that given that you only store 12 months of data, what you want is  `RANGE logdate` and not `month(log date)`. I suspect that the partition will then work with the range query (and perhaps not with the function call query)

Comment: If you want to make sure, data is in proper partition then you can try to detach partition as a table and check if data is present or not.

Answer (score 1):

According to [24.6.3 Partitioning Limitations Relating to Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-limitations-functions.html):

> In MySQL 8.0, partition pruning is supported for the TO_DAYS(), TO_SECONDS(), YEAR(), and UNIX_TIMESTAMP() functions. See Section 24.4, “[Partition Pruning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-pruning.html)”, for more information.

Since you are partitioning by MONTH(), partition pruning won't work.